# How to get TFS Work Item's Assigned To email id in C#?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem

I'm using the following code to get work items and their properties.

```
public DataTable GetBugLogData(Uri tfsUri)
    {            
        string tfsPrrojectName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tfsPrrojectName"].ToString();
        string tfsAreaPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tfsAreaPath"].ToString();            
        string workItemQuery = String.Format(@"SELECT * FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '{0}' AND [Work Item Type] = 'Bug'  AND [State] = 'Active'   AND [Area Path] = '{1}'ORDER BY [Assigned To]", tfsPrrojectName, tfsAreaPath);
        TfsTeamProjectCollection projCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri);
        WorkItemStore WIS = (WorkItemStore)projCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
        WorkItemCollection WIC = WIS.Query(workItemQuery);
        DataTable workItemsTable = new DataTable();
        workItemsTable.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[6] 
                      { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                        new DataColumn("Title", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Created By",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("State",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Assigned To",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Type",typeof(string))           

        }); 
        foreach (WorkItem wi in WIC)
        {                
            workItemsTable.Rows.Add(wi.Id, wi.Title, wi.CreatedBy.ToString(), wi.State.ToString(), (wi.Fields["Assigned To"].Value).ToString(), wi.Type.Name.ToString());                
        }
        workItemsTable.DefaultView.Sort = "[Assigned To]";
        return workItemsTable;
    }
```

Now my requirement is to get Assigned To Email Id so that i can notify him by sending a mail to his email address.I didn't find anything regarding.If anyone can suggest some code sample for this it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

We once managed to get the e-mail address of the assignedTo user with below code.

It simply connects to the active directory with full name of the user and returns the email for you.

Hope it helps!

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves a user's email address from Active Directory based on their display name
    /// </summary>
    private string GetEmailAddress(string userDisplayName)
    {
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();
        ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
        ds.Filter = String.Format("(&(displayName={0})(objectCategory=person)((objectClass=user)))", userDisplayName);

        SearchResultCollection results = ds.FindAll();
        if (results.Count == 0)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        ResultPropertyValueCollection values = results[0].Properties["mail"];
        if (values.Count == 0)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return values[0].ToString();

    }
```